# Cannot instantiate UIViewController in subclass of NSObject

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, subclass, nsobject

I don't know why any kind of UIViewController cannot be instantiate within a subclass of `NSObject`.

Attached snippets "TestControllerTwitter.h" is a subclass of `NSObject` (TestController.h)

```
#import "ServiceController.h"

@implementation TestControllerTwitter

- (TestControllerTwitter *)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return self;

    return self;
}

- (void)initTwitter
{

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
}
```

These two `*window` and `*rootViewController` cannot be instantiated as a value always is nil.

Any possibly reasons why this happens?

Comment: How do you know they're nil? Where and how are you determining that? Both, window and rootViewController are local variables, so they will not exist outside the initTwitter method.

Comment: This is a screenshot as they are nil. They are nil even within outside of the init. http://i60.tinypic.com/2e3r6dx.png

Comment: That doesn't mean anything without knowing where you had the breakpoint.  Put a log in as the last line of initTwitter, and see if window and rootViewController are nil.